# How to close responsive bootstrap menu when user touches any part of the screen surface other than the menu?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using Bootstrap framework v2.0.1 for my website's design. When the website is browsed on devices like iPad, iPhone, tablets, smart phones, etc. devices(not computers, desktops and laptops) the menu items get collapsed to one icon and get placed at top right corner of the screen. If user clicks on this icon the menu expands, if user wishes he/she can select the desired menu item, the page linked to that menu item opens and the expanded menu gets closed.
This is the current functionality of my website and it's working absolutely fine.

Now the issue I'm facing is if user clicks on menu icon, opens menu(i.e. menu gets expanded) and now he/she touches anywhere of the surface of the screen except the expanded menu the menu should again get collapse(shrink or close).

How should I achieve this? If you want any more information from my side on this issue please do let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:
Edit: If your menu has .nav-collapse class, you can use this:

```
$("body").click(function(e){ // When we click in body (all clicks are in the body ) we detect what element we are clicking.
    if ($(e.target).hasClass(".nav-collapse")){ //if the element is not our menu (#menu), we use closemenu function (we close our menu)
        closemenu();
    };
});

function closemenu(){
 // close your menu
 $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want the answer from Bootstrap perspective. Can you help me in this regard?

Comment: That code is jQuery and you need jQuery for use Bootstrap. What is the problem?

Comment: actually there are many div's with class "container" and the code to collapse the menu is $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide'); Now my issuse is how hould I write this in jQuery that if user touches anywhere within any of these div with class "container" the opened menu should get closed(The above script should get called.) Where and how should I write this code?

Comment: @PHPLover Bootstrap is simply some css and jQuery that you can use and expand on, you would add this feature as it's not part of Bootstrap 2 or 3

Comment: You would use the same and put your id or class in there

Comment: @Christina:If you could post the code as your answer it will be better for me as well as other newbies facing this issue. Can you please?

Comment: @PHPLover Check this answer now. I eddited it suggesting that your menu has the .nav-collapse class

Comment: @Héctor:One last question to you : Do I need to write anything from athe above code inside $(document).ready(function(){});?

Comment: @Héctor:I don't want to call the function on click of body. I want to call the function on all div with class "cntainer".Do I need to write anything from the above code inside $(document).ready(function(){});?

Comment: So, try this:
`$(".container").click(function(e){ // When we click in body (all clicks are in the body ) we detect what element we are clicking.
    if ($(e.target).hasClass(".nav-collapse")){ //if the element is not our menu (#menu), we use closemenu function (we close our menu)
        closemenu();
    };
});

function closemenu(){
 // close your menu
 $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide');
}`
put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try the jQuery `.focusout` event listener on the menu? http://api.jquery.com/focusout/